# IIS8 WebApi strange issue

Tags: c#, iis, threadpool

I am setting a simple WebAPI mvc application.
I have created a small action contains:
Thread.Sleep(5000);

I am trying to consume this method from console application, in 10 concurrent threads.
When the API runs on my pc (windows 10) I get all 10 responses together after 5 seconds.
When the API runs on (windows 2012) I get all 10 responses after 10X5 seconds.
For somereason, the IIS8 (on the server) do not open a thread for each client, and do it on a single thread.
No configuration had been applied to the app pool (all is default)
Server has 8 cores.

Comment: As far as I know, the IIS's worker process has the minworkthread default setting. The default value is 5. I guess this is related with your console application codes. I suggest you could try to use fidder to send the multiple request at same time.